# Send 10 message through send() while receive more message through recv()

Tags: c, sockets

server.c

```
if (retSize == -2)
{
    if (send(client_sock, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0) == -1)
    {
        close_socket(client_sock);
        close_socket(sock);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error1 sending to client.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("You have sent %d msg\n", ++cntOfMsg);
    printf("The msg is:\n %s\n", buf);
    printf("------------\n");
}
else
{
    if (send(client_sock, ret, BUF_SIZE, 0) == -1)
    {
        close_socket(client_sock);
        close_socket(sock);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error2 sending to client.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("You have sent %d msg\n", ++cntOfMsg);
    printf("The msg is:\n %s\n", ret);
    printf("------------\n");
}
```

client.c

```
while ((bytes_received = recv(sock, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0)) > 1)
{
    buf[bytes_received] = '\0';
    printf("You have received %d msg\n",++cnt);
    fprintf(stdout, "Received:\n%s\n", buf);
    printf("-----------\n");
    memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
}
```

Part of the output is as shown below:
[image: output]

NOTICE:
output like "Can't write error_log" or "syntax error" have nothing to do with the problem.Your can  believe the code I show is the only place where send or recv.

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol, it doesn't keep track of message boundaries. So there's no direct correspondence between calls to `send()` and calls to `recv()`.

Comment: You need to design a higher-level application protocol that you use to distinguish messages.

Comment: `recv()` will block util there is a message be sent,so I can't understand why the message received is not as same as the send.

Comment: Consecutive messages can be combined in the sender.

Comment: And messages can be split up, too.

Comment: @Barmar You mean I should combine what I need to send together and send it at once?

Comment: No, I mean that TCP might arbitrarily combine or split up messages that you send. You could send `foobar`, and a call to `recv()` will only return `foo`. The next call will return `bar`.

Comment: @Barmar OK,I know!!And it explains why the count of response received varies from time to time!

Comment: @sakura "*recv() will block util there is a message be sent*" - incorrect. It waits for *bytes* to be sent. It doesn't care what those bytes represent. `recv()` will return as soon as at least 1 byte is available, but it will return as many bytes as it has available. So, say the sender sends 10 100-byte messages. `recv()` might return 1 byte, 100 bytes, 1000 bytes at a time, or anywhere in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP send can segment the data however it wants.  If you send small buffers, TCP can group them and send them as a single packet after a timeout or a pending ack is received.  If you send large buffers, TCP can break them into a series of smaller packets, favoring TCP segmentation over IP fragmentation.

TCP recv can theoretically return only 1 byte, even if you think there should be more data waiting.

When using TCP to send records, you need to use a record layer that prepends each record with its length (say, a 32-bit integer in big-endian order).  The receiver must then accumulate a length (which could theoretically dribble in 1 byte at a time), and then accumulate the record content described by that length.  The receiver ping-pongs between accumulating a length and accumulating record content.

In a line-oriented protocol, you could use a newline character to delineate record boundaries.  It's really up to you to decide how to indicate boundaries within the TCP byte stream.

Answer (score 0):

On each `recv()`, you are just incrementing the `cnt` variable and printing, it doesn't represent the number of bytes received. Try printing the `bytes_received` instead.
In the same way, in the `send()` part, print the return value of `send()` call instead of `cntOfMsg`